# How big can a Changeling get

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9, changeling

In DS9 all Changelings are shown to be human size, however given their body is more like a clay substance than an actual body, have changelings ever been shown to take very large or very small forms?

Comment: Are you planning on breeding changelings?

Comment: I've marked this as a duplicate although I'll be honest, I'm not especially pleased with the answer on the dupe. I'll stick a bounty on a better answer if you don't.